# Using max_heap and min_heap interchangeably

Tags: c++

`std::priority_queue` in C++ is by default `max_heap`. A `min_heap` in C++ is a `priority_queue` having its Compare overridden to `std::greater`.

I want to have a function do extract element from one queue to push it to another. Depending on some condition, it might be from the `min_heap` to `max_heap` or the other way round. Because it is a generic operation, I write a function taking:

```
void some_operation(priority_queue<T>& give, priority_queue<T>& take)
```

However, because max_heap and min_heap were instantiated with different Compare, their class types are different and my plan wouldn't work.

Is there any good/elegant solution to this?

(I suppose this problem is more general in template classes, where the types are instantiated slightly different but the essence is mostly the same?)

Comment: You could provide some comparison type that selects which comparison to use based on a flag, then pass an instance of this into the `priority_queue` constructor. But it seems in your case, `some_operation` could be templated on the types of the queues anyway - you only care that the respective `value_type`s are compatible, they don't even have to be the same.

Comment: Both those comments seem like they might as well be answers. Why not post them as such?

Answer (score 0):

[`std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) is a template, not a class. You can't "take it by reference" without specifying all of its template arguments (but each unique combination of arguments will yield an entirely different class, a.k.a. *template instantiation*).

To work around this you can templetize your function as well:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
void some_operation(A& give, B& take) ...
```

You can later further restrict A and B to e.g. container types using SFINAE, that way you'll get (arguably) better error messages in case the function is called with unsuitable types.